# I can't send my POST method to the API with Barer Token

Tags: python, api, rest, post, azure-web-app-service

I'm new to API Rest and I'm currently trying to POST to Azure Health Data Services using Python with Databricks. To do this I need to get the token which I get through Postman without problems (in Postman my POST does work).

The data I send are these (it does work in Postman):

```
data = """
{"resourceType":"Patient","identifier":[{"use":"official","type":{"coding":[{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203","code":"NNcol"},{"system": "https://registraduria.gov.co/identificaciones","code": "CC","display": "Cedula de Ciudadania"}]},"value":"DSA2FSA1319832-K"}]}
"""
```

Then the statement I have in python to send the POST is this:

```
import requests
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict

url = 'https://workspace-test-2.fhir.azurehealthcareapis.com/Patient/'

token = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ'

headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token,  
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

print(resp.status_code)
```

This returns a error:

```
InvalidHeader: Value for header {Authorization: ('Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ',)} must be of type str or bytes, not <class 'tuple'>
```

It is worth mentioning that the TOKEN is generated on the fly, so I make sure it is valid to send the POST.

The truth is that I don't know what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing to make my POST correctly.

I will be attentive to your answers, thank you very much.

Regards.

Comment: Also, since you shared your token with everyone, you should probably expire or delete it and get a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that in this line
`headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token,` you end it with a comma. In that way, python will add a tuple to the key "Authorization" and not a string. Hence, removing the comma should do the trick